# Using keystrokes as a variable in javascript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking at using keyboard shortcuts on a webpage I'm creating. I found [Mousetrap](http://craig.is/killing/mice) that will let me do multiple keystroke shortcuts (g then i, gmail style). But I need to be able to then listen for keystroke UNTIL enter is pressed. Then I need to be able to collect those keystroke(s) and use them as a variable. Is this possible via javscript/jQuery? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have a look at the last of the examples on the page you linked to. Or if you don't want to or can specify a sequence, listen to the keys pressed and collect them in an array or string.

Comment: Lookie here: http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: Depending on your page, you could just focus on a hidden form/input and capture the SUBMIT event.